# Access imported type's static members in Aurelia view

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm using **Aurelia** with **TypeScript**.

I have a simple type with static variables like so:

```
export class MyModule {
    static foo = false;
}
```

I have an Aurelia view model like the following:

```
import {MyModule} from 'my-module';

export class MyViewModel{
    constructor() {
       MyModule.foo = true;
       console.log(MyModule.foo); // Outputs true
    }
}
```

I would like to access this static member in my view, like the following:

```
<p if.bind="MyModule.foo">
   This is displayed since foo is true.
</p>
```

However, in the view, it seems I'm unable to get the static members of the type imported in the view model.

I must be misunderstanding (at least) one of the Aurelia concepts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `MyModule` is not a member of your class.

Try this:

```
import {MyModule} from 'my-module';

export class MyViewModel{
    constructor() {
       this.myModule = MyModule;
       this.myModule.foo = true;
    }
}
```

Then

```
<p if.bind="myModule.foo">
   This is displayed since foo is true.
</p>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course it has to be exposed to the view somehow. :/ Thanks!